# Using QTeeView instead of QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtwidgets

I am a total noob in QT and C++. Sorry if I have asked something very fundamental.

I have designed a `QTreeWidget` that looks something like this.

[image]

The values inside of this `TreeWidget` are shown for a particular device 'X'. The functionality I am looking for is, how do I change/display/replace values(basically change numbers in `Value` column) based on user's selection. I at least have 10 such devices with different values for `Value` column.

I know I have to use a Model/View approach here. After intense googling I found I need to use `QTreeView` instead of `QTreeWidget`, however with TreeView I cannot add spinboxes or checkboxes. Some links also suggested to paint and recreate buttons to replicate the exact view which I felt would be an overkill for the simple use case I have.

Can someone suggest me a simple approach to achieve this? Also please let me know if I am a totally getting these concepts and approach wrong.

**Main requirement:** Replace values of this view (which is a `TreeWidget`) based on some selection.

Comment: use the property browser dude!!

Comment: you cant use `QTreeView` only instead of `QTreeWidget` ,you must also have a model(inherrited from QAbstractTableModel or your own model inherrited from QAbstractItemModel). The point is that you are having `model` for storing your data and a `view(QTreeView)` for showing that data in GUI. Also there is everything explained in [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) article.

Comment: @Robert.K Thank you for your response. I took a look at `QTreeView`. I need to use delegates for adding widgets like `QSpinBox` or a simple checkbox for that matter. And as you said a custom model inherited from QAbstractItemModel to supply data to view with delegates. Right? Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using `QTreeView` over `QTreeWidget` is its performance. If you are planning on displaying an insane amount of rows (e.g. > 1000) and are planning on having custom controls in those rows (`QComboBox` is the most expensive one), then `QTreeView` is better. The reason that `QTreeView` is more performant is because it creates your custom widgets (e.g. a `QComboBox`) on demand, when you double click on the cell and want to edit its data. `QTreeWidget`, on the contrary does not work that way. When you populate let's say 100 rows right away and on each row you call `setItemWidget()` and put in a `QComboBox`, you'll see that it takes a long time until your `QTreeWidget` is populated. With `QTreeView` you write the logic of creating and deleting the `QComboBox` in the delegate.

Also, keep in mind that for label editing and a checkbox in `QTreeWidget` you don't have to use your own `QLineEdit` or `QCheckBox`. You just make those items editable and checkable and you will get that behavior for free.

Hope this helps you in making your decision. But once again, especially that you're new to `Qt`, go with a `QTreeWidget`.

This does not mean that you cannot mimic `QTreeView` behavior in `QTreeWidget` manually. You can, by hooking into `QTreeWidget`'s event loop, or listening to its signals, or overriding some of its event methods and creating a custom widget (e.g. a `QComboBox`) on demand. But, this will be "hacky" and may have glitches and may require a long time for you to fix.

In my experience, `QTreeWidget` is one of the best UI controls in Qt. It works really well, and there is plenty of documentation on how to manipulate it in various ways in order to reach your desired behavior. Qt's own `QtPropertyBrowser`, which is used in `Qt Creator` for displaying varius UI control properties is using `QTreeWidget`.

Also, keep in mind that `QTreeWidget` also supports delegates. It is not just as customizable as `QTreeView`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently using QTreeWidget, of course with some hacks as you mentioned. QTreeView does not display the widget by default unless clicked upon. This is not a desirable behavior I am after, so I stuck to QTreeWidget.

Comment: @ShreeshaN, you may be able to achieve your mentioned behavior with a `QTreeView` as well, but it will require extra work. I prefer `QTreeWidget` and it seems like so does `Qt`, otherwise their `QtPropertyBrowser` wouldn't have been using `QTreeWidget`.

Comment: @ShreeshaN, here's a link to `QtPropertyBrowser`'s source code:
https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtpropertybrowser

Comment: @ShreeshaN, it's a bit outdated, but overall a good library, and has things like a color picker and all. So you may even use that one instead of making your own `QTreeWidget` if you have a simple key/value pair displaying widget.

Comment: And here's another library that is actively maintained and does something similar:
https://github.com/qtinuum/QtnProperty